# 'Promise' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

Tags: swift, xcode, promise

I'm trying to setup my Swift application to use the Promises framework (https://github.com/google/promises/blob/master/g3doc/index.md#creating-promises). But I cannot solve this compile time error: 'Promise' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context.

I have tried to change the Promise to another less ambiguous type. For example, I changed Promise to Promise and I changed "let dataRet = data as Data" to "let dataRet = data as String", but that hasn't worked either. I would like to note, I'm new to programming in Swift and would appreciate any help.

I'm following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@Cordavi/exploring-promises-in-swift-456c26f7c7c8

```
    //do async work
    getDataFromAPI()
        .then { (_) in }
        .catch { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }


    func getDataFromAPI() -> Promise<Data> {
        return Promise { fulfill, reject in
            //Run the query to get items
            self.appSyncClient?.fetch(query: getItemsQuery())  { (result, error) in
                //test for error
                if let error = error {
                    reject(error)
                }
                //test data is not nil
                guard let data = result.data else {
                    let error = NSError(domain: "", code: 100, userInfo: nil)
                    reject(error)
                }
                //we have the data
                let dataRet = data as Data
                fulfill(dataRet)

            }
        }
    }
```

Expected Result: getDataFromAPI returns data from the API and proceeds to execute .then { (_) in }.

Actual Result: Compiler Error: 'Promise' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing my return type to Promises.Promise .